# Is it less resource intensive to use Flutter's CustomPaint class or to use assets?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-custompainter

I am building a simple group chat app for Android and iOS. For the symbols on the buttons, they are mostly going to be simple shapes. I can add JPEGs/PNG as assets to the app, but I noticed that Flutter has this CustomPaint class. Is it less resource intensive to use this class?